# Spring source toolkit eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring, plugins

I went on the eclipse marketplace under eclipse luna, I don't know which spring source toolkit to choose because there was no one listed for sts luna, only juno, helios and kepler. Any ideas. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open **Help** > **Install New Software...** and in the resulting dialog add the update site for STS for Eclipse 4.4 (Luna): http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.4/

Once it loads all the content, you can select the parts of STS that you want.

Comment: This helped very much

Comment: If an answer solves your problem, please accept it so credit is given.